# Type Error in Flask even when passing valid html string into template to view csv as html table

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

My application collects data from the webform and searches a database on the back end using the data, and returns an HTML string for query results in the form of a table. When this string is passed into the render_template() function, I get the error: The view function did not return a valid response.

As the last step basically converts csv file to html table, I first tried doing it with pandas and even though the html string after conversion was valid, the render function did not accept it. I then tried it using the library tablib, same story.

This is what my html template file looks like. I want the results of the query to replace {{contents}}:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

{{contents}}

{% endblock %}
```

This is what my driver part of the python script looks like:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import tablib

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def results():
    contents = convert(outfile)
        render_template('results.html', contents=contents)


def convert(outfile):
    dataset = tablib.Dataset()
    with open(out_file_name, 'r') as f:
        dataset.csv = f.read()
    return str(dataset.html)
```

When I debug, I can see the html string for the csv file created as value of dataset.html from the convert function, but i do not understand why it is not being accepted by the render_template function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import tablib

app = Flask(__name__)

# Define this function before it is actually called:

def convert(outfile):
    dataset = tablib.Dataset()
    with open(out_file_name, 'r') as f:
        dataset.csv = f.read()
    return str(dataset.html)

# You forgot `return` and indented the last line of this too much:

@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def results():
    contents = convert(outfile)
    return render_template('results.html', contents=contents)
```